# SQL Cursor Syntax Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

Im getting this error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CostTest_02, Line 43
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

With "GO" underlined in red I've been looking for the error for a while and I can't find! I'm not very experienced with cursors( this is the first one I've written) If anyone can spot it or any other errors I'd be very thankful

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwB1w.jpg <----- picture is a lot more clear(recommended)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE CostTest_02
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Issue_id int;
DECLARE @Master_id int;
DECLARE @Issue_table varchar(255);
DECLARE @price real;
DECLARE @rowcount bigint;


DECLARE cost_cursor cursor FOR
SELECT [Issue Id], [Master Id], [Issue Table], [Price]
from Adhoc_datafix..[Issue Table]
FOR UPDATE OF ADHOC_DATAFIX..[Issue Cost];

OPEN cost_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor into @Issue_ID, @Master_id, @Issue_table, @Price

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

Select count(*) from @Issue_Table
set @Rowcount = @@rowcount

UPDATE ADHOC_DATAFIX..[Issue Cost]
set  [Issue Id] = @Issue_ID ,
[Master Issue Id] = @Master_ID ,
[Row Count] = (Select count(*) from @Issue_Table), --@Rowcount,
[Cost] = CAST(@Rowcount * @price as money)

WHERE CURRENT OF cost_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor
END

close cost_cursor;

DEALLOCATE cost_cursor;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an `END` statement for your stored procedure. Just add that before `GO`

Comment: Yes this helped a lot actually, but im still not sure about the 
two different type of FETCH that I'm using surely only one is needed?

Comment: you need both fetches, but they should both be `FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor into @Issue_ID, @Master_id, @Issue_table, @Price`. The first fetch gets the first matched row and sets up the initial `fetch_status`, i.e. did it find something. After each loop, you call fetch again to try and get another row and update `fetch_status`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I was thinking just needed confirmation

Answer (score 1):

<strike>My guess is that the line `FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor` near the bottom of the script should be `FETCH NEXT FROM cost_cursor into @Issue_ID, @Master_id, @Issue_table, @Price`</strike>
.

Sorry, on second look this line:

```
Select count(*) from @Issue_Table
```

does not make sense since @Issue_table is not actually a table, it's a nvarchar.
In runtime, that is transferred to:

```
Select count(*) from 'Value of issue table field'
```

which, to put it simply, does not work.
If you want to dynamically get the count from a table, take a look at this [seminal article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: About the fetches, they are both needed, since sql server cursors use something like a [loop-and-a-half](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half)

Comment: @Issue_Table contains a string to a table that actually exists which is what I'm trying to select all from, I don't think this is dynamic SQL but I still need to figure out a way of doing this? Do you know how

Comment: @Callum That is exactly what dynamic SQL is.

Comment: Would it work in this situation as the table name will be changing each time the cursor is looped?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact problem that dynamic sql is solving.

Comment: Sorry :(. I'm not the brightest person when it comes to SQL but you have helped me a lot i've used 

SELECT @sql = 'Select count(*) from ' + quotename(@Issue_table) EXEC(@sql)

 sound okay?

Comment: @Callum, yes, if you control the value of the Issue_table field. If you do not, this might expose you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)

Comment: Ahh Okay! Thank you for help SWeko! It means a lot :)